# RegExp - 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to redirect one of my domains to another domain. I have a domain which is e.g

`http://www.test-url.com`

`http://test-url.com`

Now i have URLs like:
`http://test-url.com/category/hoodies.html`

I want that this (and all other category urls or sub-urls) urls are redirected to:
`http://www.test-url.com/category/hoodies.html`

At the moment all urls like: `http://testurl.com/category/hoodies.html` are redirected to `http://www.testurl.com` - without the category-page.

I tried it with this code, but it is not working. I guess the problem is, that the rewrite-condition matches the www.-domain, too...right?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-url.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^testurl.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test-url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried it with the Negation like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.test-url.com$ [NC]
```

This worked, but i can't do it like this, because there is another domain involved...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test-?url\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test-url.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello anubhava, thanks - but the problem is not that i have 3 lines of code and now have one. At the moment, the category-url without "www" is redirected to the main page with www. - but i want to be redirected to the category-page with www.

Comment: Problem was that in your code 2 RewriteCond lines were `ANDed` together and return false and therefore RewriteRule will never be executed.